# TagHelpers onchange event for Dropdownlist in mvc 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am having a dropdown and I want to bind a Jquery onchange event to the TagHelpers select tag. Below is my code.

```
 <select asp-for="BusinessType"
         asp-items="@Model.BusinessTypeCollection">
 </select>
```

How can I bind bind the onchange event inline of the tag.

Something like this.

```
 <select asp-for="BusinessType"
         asp-items="@Model.BusinessTypeCollection"
         onchange ="something">
 </select>
```

Comment: I am just looking for a syntax in mvc 6 select TagHelpers to call a Jquery function or javascript function.

Answer (score 8):

`onchange` is the correct attribute to use if you want to specify it inline. You just need to make sure you are (a) invoking it and (b) that function is available in global scope.

For example:

```
<select asp-for="BusinessType"
        asp-items="Model.BusinessTypeCollection"
        onchange="test()"></select>

@section scripts {
    <script>
        function test() {
            alert('hi');
        }
    </script>
}
```

That being said, a **much better way** to do this is by binding the event in JavaScript (I'm using jQuery here as you have mentioned it in the question) and only reference the element by it's `id` attribute.

```
<select asp-for="BusinessType"
        asp-items="Model.BusinessTypeCollection"></select>

@section scripts {
    <script>
        $("#BusinessType").on("change", function () {
            alert("changed!");
        });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: This is a perfect answer